# One Odd-Sized page in Pages Document for PDF

Tags: pages, iwork, numbers

Need to embed a Numbers spreadsheet in a Pages doc that will “live” as a PDF. Generating a scaled image that I then embed results in mediocre resolution.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no way to scale your numbers doc small enough to fit on a pages sized page, you'll have to use a larger paper size (e.g. legal).

If you *only* want your numbers doc to be a different size, you'll need to handle them separately. I'm not aware of any way to change the dimensions of a single page in pages directly but...

If the document will "live" as a PDF, why not export the pages doc to PDF in standard Letter or A4 size without your spreadsheet.

Then [create a custom page size](http://i-work-in-pages.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-set-custom-dimensions-for-pages.html) in your Numbers doc to fit the spreadsheet as a whole and export that to pdf.

Finally, use preview to [combine the two documents.](http://www.imore.com/how-easily-insert-new-pages-pdf-preview-mac)

Comment: Thanks!

Had no idea Preview could do this!